# Facing an overflow issue with a Hackerrank problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm facing a weird overflow issue with a [Hackerrank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gridland-metro/problem). Here's the brief of the problem statement.

There is a 2D array, and in each row of the array there are lines starting at one cell and ending at another cell (left to right in the same row). Now there can be multiple lines in one row and they can certainly overlap one another. The task is to find the number of unoccupied cells in the 2D array.

It is important to note that the dimensions of the array can be really big upto `10^9`. So this was my approach

- Use a map that would have the row number as the key and a vector of pairs as its corresponding value. The pairs are nothing but the start and end index of a line in that row. `row -> vector<pair<int, int>>`
- Sort each such vector by the first element of the pair (i.e the start index of the interval).
- Merge the overlapping intervals for all the rows. For each merged interval calculate its length `wR - wL + 1` where `wL` and `wR` are the start and end indexes of the interval respectively. Add the length of all these intervals and store in a variable `sum`
- Lastly, subtract that `sum` from `n*m` to get the number of unoccupied cells.

Here is the relevant code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define pii pair<int, int>
#define mp make_pair
#define ulld unsigned long long int
#define ff first
#define ss second
using namespace std;

void sortMap(unordered_map<int, vector<pii>> &dict){
    unordered_map<int, vector<pii>>::iterator it;
    for(it=dict.begin(); it!=dict.end(); it++){
        vector<pii> &temp = it->second;
        sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    }
}

ulld compute(unordered_map<int, vector<pii>> &dict, int n, int m){
    unordered_map<int, vector<pii>>::iterator it;
    ulld sum = 0;
    for(it = dict.begin(); it != dict.end(); it++){
        vector<pii> temp = it->second;
        int n = temp.size();
        int WL = temp[0].ff, 
            WR = temp[0].ss;

        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++){
            if(WR >= temp[i+1].ff && WR < temp[i+1].ss){
                // partial overlap
                WR = temp[i+1].ss;
            }else if(WL <= temp[i+1].ff && WR >= temp[i+1].ss){
                // complete overlap
                // nothing to consider here
            }else{
                // no overlap
                // compute the exisiting window size so far
                sum += WR - WL + 1;
                WL = temp[i+1].ff;
                WR = temp[i+1].ss;
            }
        }
        sum += (WR - WL + 1);
    }
    ulld ans = ((ulld)n * (ulld)m) - sum;
    return ans;
}

// Complete the gridlandMetro function below.
ulld gridlandMetro(int n, int m, int k, vector<vector<int>> track) {
    unordered_map<int, vector<pii>> dict;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        int row = track[i][0]-1;
        pii bounds = mp(track[i][1]-1,track[i][2]-1);

        if(dict.find(row) == dict.end()){
            vector<pii> temp;
            temp.push_back(bounds);
            dict.insert(pair<int, vector<pii>>(row, temp));
        }else{
            vector<pii> temp = dict[row];
            temp.push_back(bounds);
            dict[row]=temp;
        }
    }
    sortMap(dict);
    return compute(dict, n, m);
}
```

I've unlocked a particular test case for which the code was failing. This test case consists of large numbers in the order of `10^9` and the result is in the order of `10^18` which are as per expectation.

What I don't understand is, why I'm getting garbage values in negative when dealing with large numbers despite using appropriate data types: `long long, unsigned long long int`?

Would really appreciate some help on this! Thanks for showing patience.

Comment: Yuo have code, and you have a failure case. Either fire up the debugger, or post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I just found out the issue.
The problem was with the pre-written code or template that was provided.
It was expecting an integer while my code was returning a larger value. 
So changing,

`int result = gridlandMetro(n, m, k, track);` to

`ulld result = gridlandMetro(n, m, k, track);` fixed it.

I did not expect that the boilerplate code would be faulty.